# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' in the line 9

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url="https://news.ycombinator.com/")
page = response.text
```

this is a code for webscraping.when I run it, it gives me an error in this line
print(soup_title.get_text()). my mentor typed the same code but did not got an error why.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
soup_title = soup.find(name="a", class_="spacer")
print(soup_title.get_text())
```

Comment: Very simply your `soup.find(name="a", class_="spacer")` did not succeed, so `None` was returned. You have to check for that.

Comment: i checked it in website many times there is same class and anchor tag

Comment: Looking at the html, its a "tr" tag, not "a".

Comment: *"my mentor typed the same code but did not got an error"* Are you **sure** that it was the same? Same site, same parser, same `find` arguments?

Answer (score 0):

To print all the titles you can use this:

```
titles = soup.find_all(name="span", class_="titleline")
for title in titles:
    print(title.findChildren("a")[0].text)
```